# SQL SERVER - Filter SELECT Columns using CASE

Tags: sql-server

Is there a work-around for this?

```
SELECT 
    CASE @GROUP
    WHEN 'A' THEN GRADE1, GRADE2
    WHEN 'B' THEN GRADE1, GRADE4, GRADE5
    WHEN 'C' THEN GRADE3, GRADE6
    WHEN 'D' THEN GRADE2, GRADE5, GRADE6
    END
FROM QuizBeeRep
```

I want to have multiple THEN in order to filter which columns to select based on the @GROUP.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `CASE` expression can only return a single value.  And the only way to control the number of columns appearing in the query would require dynamic SQL.

Comment: Please provide some input and output data for your question. It helps more clearly...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `case` expression in such a manner.

Alternatively you can do something like:

```
if @GROUP = 'A'
   select GRADE1, GRADE2
   FROM QuizBeeRep
else if @GROUP = 'B
   select GRADE1, GRADE4, GRADE5
   FROM QuizBeeRep
... and so on
```

Comment: This is what I am avoiding to do. Because this is just a sample query with the same logic. I have multiple Joined tables and parameters.

Comment: @theo Well... you can first insert all the data (using your complex logic) into temporary table and then select columns you need according to condition from that table.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance the number of column (and it's fixed) you can do something like this (without using dynamic SQL).  It works if the columns have same dataype (otherwise, in some cases, you should add proper CAST):

```
 SELECT 
        CASE @GROUP
        WHEN 'A' THEN GRADE1
        WHEN 'B' THEN GRADE1
        WHEN 'C' THEN GRADE3
        WHEN 'D' THEN GRADE2
        END  AS COL1
, CASE @GROUP
        WHEN 'A' THEN GRADE2
        WHEN 'B' THEN GRADE4
        WHEN 'C' THEN GRADE6
        WHEN 'D' THEN GRADE5
        END AS COL2
,CASE @GROUP
        WHEN 'A' THEN NULL
        WHEN 'B' THEN GRADE5
        WHEN 'C' THEN NULL 
        WHEN 'D' THEN GRADE6
        END  AS COL3
    FROM QuizBeeRep
```

Comment: Yes I Know (I was dreaming...) Try this one please, but I know, it's bit clumsy...